# What is wrong with this Pig Latin program?

Tags: c++

**What it's supposed to do**

My piglatin program is supposed to take a phrase from user input and output it into pig latin. Basically it would turn a word such as "hello" into "ellohay".

---

**My problem**

When I input `hello my man` the output is `ellohay y man an may` and when I just input `hello my` the output is `ellohay y may`. As you can see, after it translates the first word successfully, it struggles on the second word. It places a space after the `y` and `may`I cannot figure out for the life of me why this keeps happening. The output is even stranger when I input more than two words, as shown above. What I want to happen is for it to output `ellohay ymay anmay` when I input `hello my man`. Code is below. Thanks!

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void phrase_Parser(string); // Goes through phrase and looks for ' ' to then pass to pigLatin_Translator()
void pigLatin_Translator(string);
int main()
{
    string phrase; //used for user word or phrase to be translated to piglatin
    cout << "Enter any word: ";
    getline(cin, phrase); 

    phrase_Parser(phrase);
    return 0;
}

void phrase_Parser(string phrase) {
    int startCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        if (phrase[i] == ' ') {

            string word = phrase.substr(startCount, i);
            startCount = (i + 1); // decides where to start the word next time it is ran through

            pigLatin_Translator(word); // runs word through translator
        }
    }
}
void pigLatin_Translator(string word) {
    string partOne;
    string partTwo;

    for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
        if (word[0] == 'q' && word[1] == 'u') {
            cout << word.substr(2, word.length()) << word.substr(0, 2) << "ay ";
            break;
        }
         else if ((word[x] == 'a') || (word[x] == 'e') || (word[x] == 'i') || (word[x] == 'o') || (word[x] == 'u') || (word[x] == 'y')) {
            partOne = word.substr(x, word.length()); //from first vowel to end of word
            partTwo = word.substr(0, x); // from first letter to first vowel, not including the vowel
            cout << partOne << partTwo << "ay "; // adding "ay" to the end of the word
            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just use `>>`, you will read whitespace-separated words. You don't need to do split into words by hand.

Comment: @RawN, here is something to read: [Wikipedia Article on Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) :P

Comment: Your word splitter is not correctly splitting "my man" into two words. I am investigating.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: +1 for the debugger suggestion, an invaluable tool. That's really all I did, stepped through the code looking for the first sign of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the line `string word = phrase.substr(startCount, i);`

You are using `substr` incorrectly. The second argument to `substr` is the length of the substring you wish to extract. Replace `i` with `i-startCount` and you should be good to go.

Alternatively, search for a nicer way to split strings. There are a number of options that are much easier than doing it manually.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will be researching other ways to split strings. Thanks again!